# client-side extension to remember personal voting history

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics, extension

As far as I can reconstruct, the user profile once had a votes tab, where anyone could see their own votes. That functionality was removed at some point, and is unlikely to return.

Reference:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/89989/personal-voting-history-review-page

Nevertheless, I still would like to be able to see my own voting history, and perhaps even run some statistic evaluation on it.

Now since there is no support for this server-side, and since the data-dumps do not include voting information, the only way seems to be with some sort of client-side extension, like a userscript.

What would be a good approach to develop such an extension, and are there any good existing extensions for stackoverflow that one could use as a base?
For example, which js-functions or http-requests would I have to catch to capture the casting of a vote.

Or is there already an extension that does this, which I have not found yet?

Comment: @lunboks Good point, thanks! Did not know about that one

Comment: Is voting info available through the API? I didn't see it when I scanned the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the response has been underwhelming so far, but fortunately the powers that be decided to restore the voting tab on the profile page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/130380/182796

So a client-side extension is no longer required.